# Is there any way to write java code in an ATL Project? or ATL transformation code in a EMF project?

Tags: java, model, transformation, eclipse-emf

When I open an ATL (Atlas Transformation Language) Project and I try to write a java class, I won't allow me to do that saying "source is not a java project"
Again If I Open an EMF empty project, I can open the Java class but ATL transformation does not work as it can't produce the .asm file.
Is there a way to combine both these technologies as ATL is based on EMF so I hoped it would be possible?
I tried to add ATL core Plug-in Dependencies to my EMF project, but still it didn't work.
Any help would be much appreciated because I am badly stuck. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This probably has to do with your project's nature / builder, try to right click > properties on an ATL project and a Java project and see if there is any way to enable the Java/ATL nature or add the missing ATL builder to your Java project maybe.